# Check For Third-Party App Installation

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-8

In my app **B**, I need to check if app **A** ever installed. If **A** has been installed, **B** will invoke **A**.

If **A** has not been installed, **B** will go to marketplace to download **A**.

how to implement this???
ANY ADVICE WILL BE GREAT！
THANKS!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is currently no way for you to check whether a third-party application was installed on the device. However, it you are the publisher of that application, you can use:

```
IEnumerable<Package> apps = Windows.Phone.Management.Deployment.InstallationManager.FindPackagesForCurrentPublisher();
apps.First().Launch(string.Empty);
```

This capability is documented [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj207014%28v=vs.105%29.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

If app A and app B are not from the same publisher there is no direct way to get this. However, if you were able to work with the developer of app B to register a custom URI association, app A could interact with the app by launching the custom URI.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj206987(v=vs.105).aspx