# How to check if user has installed specific app on the WP8 device

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I'm developing an app for WP8.  Can I check (programmaticaly) if wp8 device has some specific app installed (i.e. WP8 Facebook app)?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Check For Third-Party App Installation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15870780/check-for-third-party-app-installation)

Answer (score 4):

You cannot get the list of applications that are installed on the Windows Phone that are published by someone **other than the publisher of the calling application**.

**There is a way**, however, to get the list of applications that are installed on the device and are originating from the publisher of the caller app. Here is [what I am talking about](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj207014%28v=vs.105%29.aspx):

```
IEnumerable<Package> apps = Windows.Phone.Management.Deployment.InstallationManager.FindPackagesForCurrentPublisher();
apps.First().Launch(string.Empty);
```

This required your app to run on a Windows Phone 8 device.

Comment: Hmmm... Thank you.
I also checked http://developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/URI_Association_Schemes_List. My intention is not to lunch some external app, but simply to check if some app exists on the device. Those apps that I need to check are actually Microsoft made (FB, LinkedIn and Twitter). So, there is no way I can do that?

Comment: Yes, Even though app from Microsoft Corporation, you cannot check. You can only check the apps which published by you. Dont fail to mark as an answer if it helps you