# How to check if Facebook is installed or not WP8?

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

Below link help to open facebook app, If, installed

```
Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(new Uri("fb://"))
```

I need to know facebook installed or not like below condition,

```
if(installed)
{
//my code
}
else
{
"not installed"
};
```

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to check if user has installed specific app on the WP8 device](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19158610/how-to-check-if-user-has-installed-specific-app-on-the-wp8-device)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot check if third party apps like Facebook, Soundhound are installed. The only thing that you can check is the list of **apps those you published** that are installed on the device.

You can try this out,

```
var success = await Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(new Uri("fb://"));

if (success)
{
   // URI launched
}
else
{
   // URI launch failed
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Nop, you can't check whether a third party application is installed unless if it's an application that you developed.

Reference: [How to check if user has installed specific app on the WP8 device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19158610/)