# Detect application installation on Windows Phone

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

Is any way to detect installation of some application on Windows Phone 8? I need to check from my application if Facebook and Twitter is installed on phone

Comment: No there is not. Why do you think your app needs to know this? Whatever you're trying to do can probably be achieved another way. I can think of no scenario where knowing what apps are present can benefit your app. Twitter/Facebook links will go to the appropriate website if no app is installed.

Comment: Take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/a/19158818/1876572

Answer (score 0):

Sorry but there isn't a way to know what other apps are installed on Windows Phone 8.1 and below.  I have asked this question to Microsoft as I have a similar need.  I have asked to have it included in next release of the OS.

I'm curious, why do you need to know if Facebook or Twitter are available?