# Check if there is an App present which responds to a given URI

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

On WindowsPhone you can launch some applications by using the URI associations. Now I understand and implemented the launching of another App by using:

```
Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(new System.Uri("<custom-uri-scheme>:<path>"));
```

But before we tell the Launcher to start the other App we would like to check if the App is actually installed.

Is it possible to check if there is an App present which responds to a given URI? I am looking for something similar to iOS's `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:<url>]`

Comment: It looks like they realised that that functionality didn't exist in Phone 8 since [QueryUriSupported](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.system.launcher.queryurisupportasync.aspx) is coming in Mobile 10.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Windows 8.x**
No, currently windows phone OS 8.0/8.1 doesn't allow [1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13617515/546896) you check if certain third party app is installed on the device or not. Though you can check if the user has installed other app of yours, if the publisher ID is same [2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15871975/546896).

1: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13617515/546896

2: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15871975/546896

**Windows 10**
On Windows Phone 10 it is possible to use [Launcher.QueryUriSupportAsync](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.system.launcher.queryurisupportasync.aspx)